# Lisp interpreter in Flex/Bison

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, context-free-grammar

I have the following Bison grammar:

```
%%
input:
    expression { cout << $1 << endl;}
    ;

expression:
    INT
    | OP PLUS expression expression CP {$$ = $3 + $4;}
    | OP MINUS expression expression CP {$$ = $3 - $4;}
    | OP MULT expression expression CP {$$ = $3 * $4;}
    | OP DIV expression expression CP {$$ = $3 / $4;}
    | OP PLUS expression expression exprseries CP {$$ = $3 + $4 + $5;}
    ;

exprseries:
    expression
    | expression exprseries {$$ = $1 + $2;}
    ;
%%
```

Where `OP` and `CP` are open and close parentheses respectively.

I want it to recognize `(+ <exp1> <exp2> ... <expn>)` and calculate the sum. Unfortunately it only recognizes `(+ INT INT ... INT)` and `(+ INT <exp1> <exp2> <exp3>)`

Comment: Works for me. Please provide a [mcve] (Note: **complete**; read that link) and be more explicit about the error (eg. include a precise input which fails).

Comment: Here's one that does not work: `(+2 (+2 3) (+2 3))`. Fails with syntax error from bison. I can add full code in an hour

Comment: Prints 12 for me. Did you verify that your lexer is producing the correct tokens? (hint: if you are using flex, provide the `-d` flag to trace the return values.)

Comment: My fault, the code was actually `(+2 (+2 3) (+2 3) (+2 3))`

Comment: I figured out the issue. I was using bison with the main just being `yyparse()` so i could use it interactively, but that was joining my inputs together I believe.

Comment: Yes, bison parsers read from the beginning to the end of a file. (Which is what you would expect, really. That's what compilers do.) If you want to recognize multiple lines, you need to state that explicitly in the grammar.